# Clicking html button programmatically, is not passing the data attribute JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a Bootstrap modal with this button 
`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="send" data-btn-action="send">Send</button>`

On the main page, where the modal is, I have the same button as above but with a **submit** type. So, on click of the modal's button, it triggers the button on the page. It works fine, but the data attribute is **NULL** if it's triggered from the modal but if I click on it directly, I get the **data attribute** value

My JS

`let actionBtn = $("#send").attr('data-btn-action');` 
Thank you.

Comment: So you have two buttons both with the ID of send? If that is true, that is going to cause your problems. I would have each button with a different ID.

Comment: No, they are of different names for the modal, it's a class I used